# unable to target a button tag inside div

Tags: html, css

I have html structure like this

```
<div class="buttons controls">
    <a href="#B"><button>Next</button></a>
    <a href="#Z"><button>Previous</button></a>
</div>
```

I am targetting the buttons

```
.controls>button
.buttons.controls>button
```

but it is not working. I want to know why??

Comment: FYI: You can not have a `button` inside an `a` element, that’s invalid HTML.

Comment: why is it so? @CBroe

Comment: Because the HTML specification says so. Both are “interactive” elements – and you could for example have a button that would submit a form inside an `a` element that links somewhere – and then the desired result would be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because your `<button>` element is not a child of `div.controls`. You could use `.controls a > button` or `.controls > a > button`

`A > E`

> Any E element that is a child (i.e. direct descendant) of an A element

**[MDN Documentation - Selectors based on relationships](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships)**

**EDIT:**

`.controls > a > button` is more specific. So it will only be applied  when your HTML looks like this

```
<div class="buttons controls">
    <a href='#'>
        <button>MyButton</button>
    </a>
</div>`
```

`.controls a button` is a more general selector, so it would also be applied with a HTML like this -

```
<div class="buttons controls">
    <div class="myDiv">
        <a href="#H">
            <button>MyButton</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see, you could also specify a `div` as parent of `<a>` element and the CSS-Style will still be applied.

Comment: is there any difference between `.controls a > button` or `.controls > a > button`

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer as an additional answer on your comment

Answer (score 1):

Because .button is inside of the anchor therefore it is not a direct descendant of the .controls class as you are trying to do in your css

try this:

```
.controls .button {
   /* style here */
}
```

or like stated in the answer above

```
.controls > a > button {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```